# If True put item from queryset on end of the list

Tags: python, django, list, django-queryset

I have app when I want to check if date is in the past. If it is true, I want to put this item on the end of the list.

Here is my code but it is not working and I get error message:

```
'QuerySet' object has no attribute 'extend'
```

My code:

```
    for i in queryset:
        if i.date_end < now():
            queryset.extend(queryset.pop(queryset.index(i)))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `QuerySet` does not support all common `list` operations. You should not modify any collection while iterating it anyway. Why don't you order the `QuerySet` by `date_end` in descending order:

```
queryset = queryset.order_by('-date_end')
```

That way, all the items of the past will be at the end.

Answer (score 0):

You can reach it this way:

```
for index, item in enumerate(queryset):
  if item.date_end < now():
      queryset[-1], queryset[index] =  item, queryset[-1]
```

If you don't want to swap and just move it to the end so:

```
for index, item in enumerate(queryset):
  if item.date_end < now():
      queryset.insert(len(queryset)-1, queryset.pop(index))
```